# Get info from a column

Tags: r

I have this column in a data frame of R Studio and I want to get the info inside. This is how one of the lines in the column looks like :

```
<goal>
   <value>
      <comment>n</comment>
      <stats>
         <goals>1</goals>
         <shoton>1</shoton>
      </stats>
      <event_incident_typefk>71</event_incident_typefk>
      <elapsed>2</elapsed>
      <player1>43372</player1>
      <sortorder>0</sortorder>
      <team>8370</team>
      <id>2305454</id>
      <n>34</n>
      <type>goal</type>
      <goal_type>n</goal_type>
   </value>
   <value>
      <comment>n</comment>
      <stats>
         <goals>1</goals>
         <shoton>1</shoton>
      </stats>
      <event_incident_typefk>71</event_incident_typefk>
      <elapsed>4</elapsed>
      <player1>2983</player1>
      <sortorder>0</sortorder>
      <team>8603</team>
      <id>2305455</id>
      <n>30</n>
      <type>goal</type>
      <goal_type>n</goal_type>
   </value>
   <value>
      <comment>n</comment>
      <stats>
         <goals>1</goals>
         <shoton>1</shoton>
      </stats>
      <event_incident_typefk>71</event_incident_typefk>
      <elapsed>62</elapsed>
      <player1>358127</player1>
      <sortorder>0</sortorder>
      <team>8370</team>
      <id>2305677</id>
      <n>33</n>
      <type>goal</type>
      <goal_type>n</goal_type>
   </value>
</goal>
```

I want to see if there is a way in order to look like this: ex.

Goal Goals Shoton

..n.......1.........1

and so on..

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example including what you already tried and what you expect the output to look like (in terms of actual data, what you showed could be interpreted in many ways).

Comment: Look into `XML::xmlToDataFrame()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have is an XML string. You can parse it to transform into a list and do everything you need from there. Just an example, following what you asked for:

```
test <- "<goal><value><comment>n</comment><stats><goals>1</goals><shoton>1</shoton></stats><event_incident_typefk>71</event_incident_typefk><elapsed>2</elapsed><player1>43372</player1><sortorder>0</sortorder><team>8370</team><id>2305454</id><n>34</n><type>goal</type><goal_type>n</goal_type></value><value><comment>n</comment><stats><goals>1</goals><shoton>1</shoton></stats><event_incident_typefk>71</event_incident_typefk><elapsed>4</elapsed><player1>2983</player1><sortorder>0</sortorder><team>8603</team><id>2305455</id><n>30</n><type>goal</type><goal_type>n</goal_type></value><value><comment>n</comment><stats><goals>1</goals><shoton>1</shoton></stats><event_incident_typefk>71</event_incident_typefk><elapsed>62</elapsed><player1>358127</player1><sortorder>0</sortorder><team>8370</team><id>2305677</id><n>33</n><type>goal</type><goal_type>n</goal_type></value></goal>"

vector <- unlist(xmlToList(test))
summary <- vector[c("value.goal_type", "value.stats.goals", "value.stats.shoton")]
names(summary) <- c("Goal", "Goals", "Shoton")
```